# PHP: Variable not accessible defined in include/require file using absolute path

Tags: php, include, require, absolute-path

I am finding difficulty in accessing a variable defined in the include file.

My include file is present in the root and it has a variable `$x`:

`localhost/dir_name/include.php`

I am including the `include.php` file in `file.php` present in the sub directory :

`localhost/dir_name/sub_directory/file.php`

But every time, the file.php gives the error of `undefined variable $x`

The weird thing is that when I use a relative path to include the `include.php`, it works perfectly. Like this:

`include '../include.php';`

ALSO, it works when using `realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`. Like this:

`include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\dir_name\include.php'`

But it never works for the absolute path. I also tried making the variable global but didn't helped me and the `include.php` file is also included correctly. It is not giving me any other error except this undefined variable.

Before asking, I tried finding this on SO, but couldn't find the answer to this error.

I am currently using the `realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])` as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` is not an absolute path. PHP reads the actual directories on your computer, not the ones from the URL.

Try `echo realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I tried that it gave me the path like `C:\xampp\htdocs`... So, do I have to use either realpath method or the `dirname(__DIR__)` ? I cannot include the url path?

Comment: @Butterfruit: That's right. PHP reads physical directories, not URL ones.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Well, include/require can be used with HTTP URLs as well (if the server config allows it) – but of course the result is a fundamentally different one, because an include via file system embeds the PHP _code_ of the file, whereas an include via HTTP only embeds the _output_ of the URL.

Comment: @CBroe: I was waiting for someone to say that. 1. It's insecure 2. You can't include PHP code that way. 3. Don't, just don't.

Comment: That was just in response to your statement, _“PHP reads physical directories, not URL ones”_ – I was not _advising_ to do this. (And of course you _can_ include PHP code this way – you just have to make sure it does not get _parsed_ by the server delivering it – f.e. by putting it into a `.txt` file instead of `.php`. Again, I’m not _recommending_ this; this is just for clarification.)

Comment: Oh yes that can also be a scenario. I never thought about that, I will be careful next time. @CBroe