# php variable not going with include()

Tags: php

i'm trying to pass variables from `userInfo.php` to `flips.php` but for some reason the variables don't go through.
When i do `echo "hello";` in the userInfo.php then i do see 'hello' in the website but when i do:

```
if (isset($variable)) {
 echo "it is set!";
} else {
 echo "nope!";
}
```

Then it returns 'nope!' even though i have set `$variable` in `userInfo.php`.

**userInfo.php:**

```
<?php
$variable = "hello everyone!";
echo "hello!";
```

**flips.php:**

```
<?php
include ('userInfo.php');

if (isset($variable)) {
 echo "it is set!";
} else {
 echo "nope!";
}
```

**Website output:**
`hello!nope!`

what am i doing wrong so `flips.php` doesn't see `$variable`?

---

**Edit (the real code from my website):**

**flips.php:**

```
include ('../csgodonut/application/views/steamauth/userInfo.php');
if (isset($steamprofile["personaname"])) {
  echo "yes!";
} else {
  echo "nope..";
}
```

**userInfo.php:**

```
$steamprofile['personaname'] = "Smokey";
echo "test";
```

Website: www.csgodonut.com (you have to login to steam in order to see the `hello! nope..`)
flips.php location: `csgodonut/application/views/gebruiker/home/flips.php`
userInfo.php location: `csgodonut/application/views/steamauth/userInfo.php`

Comment: impossible based on what you have provided, make sure to show your full code

Comment: this iseverything, only the `$variable` is called `$steamprofile` in my code, other then that it is exactly the same

Comment: so no `<?php` ? seems unlikley

Comment: i meant the code is the same, `<?php` is in my code

Comment: i'll edit my question with my exact code, maybe i'm just dumb

Comment: yes i'm including `userInfo.php` in `home.php` and there it's working fine, also i'm calling `flips.php` in the browser

Comment: Your code is working fine for me on the CLI: `php flips.php`. How are you calling it from the browser?

Comment: Have you explicitly set the `include path` anywhere? You ought to check the include path using `get_include_path()` &/or set with `set_include_path()` - maybe also check in `flips.php` what files have been included with `var_dump(get_included_files());` ~ or try with `require` to see any errors it may throw

Comment: And show us the dirs/files structure in your file system.

Comment: when i try `var_dump(get_included_files());` it returns: `array(1) { [0]=> string(86) "csgodonut/application/views/gebruiker/home/flips.php" } @RamRaider , and @aendeerei do you mean the url?

Comment: ok - so it has NOT included the `userinfo.php` file ~ are they in the same directory?

Comment: Yes. So: 1) Show us the url. 2) Show us where the dirs/files reside EXACTLY.

Comment: that's weird, because you can see the echo from `userInfo.php`...
they are not in the same directory:
flips.php: `csgodonut/application/views/gebruiker/home/flips.php`
userInfo.php: `csgodonut/application/views/steamauth/userInfo.php`

Comment: No, it is nothing weird. As said, it's about the variable scope of the vars included in a file which is included in another file. Could you please reedit the question with url and structure? Thanks

Comment: the url is www.csgodonut.com , but you'll have to login using steam to go to the homepage, and you can see where the files are in my previous comment

Comment: yes, `home.php` on top and `flips.php` loaded on the bottom

Comment: You could propably just include the userInfo.php in the home.php and the variable scope would be ok

Comment: i already tried that, but then it isn't set either

Comment: Aaa, there it is: You are including userInfo.php in flips.php. Then you include flips.php in home.php and access home.php from browser. In that moment it doesn't work. Am I right?

Comment: i use a ajax $.get to get `flips.php` but then the include in flips.php should still work right?

Comment: Put this line(s) in home.php (as the first lines): `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and refresh home.php.

Comment: That is not clear with ajax. First things first...

Comment: did it, don't see any difference though

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the variable itself? ie echo $steamprofile['personaname']; In the flips.php

Comment: yep, then it doesn't show anything

Comment: what about the relative include: 
include 'csgodonut/application/views/steamauth/userInfo.php'; ? EDIT: Nvm I realized they are in different structure

Comment: that doesn't work either, still echoing "nope.."

Comment: Smokey: home.php is on top, and flips.php on the bottom. Of which page??!

Comment: When you log in on my website you go to the homepage, there you see `home.php` (the navigation bar, the part that says "joining games doesn't..." and the "coinflip, refresh and create" part.) in home.php i use ajax  `$.get("../application/views/gebruiker/home/flips.php", function(data, status) { $("#titlebalk").html(data); });` to load `flips.php`

Comment: Have you tried any other variable in the userInfo.php ie. $array = array();
$string = "some string"; $integer = 5; and then try to access those?

Comment: Ok... So, the homepage is home.php. Where is it located?

Comment: i did @user3647971 , they didn't show up either.
`home.php` is located in the same folder as `flips.php`
so: `csgodonut/application/views/gebruiker/home/home.php`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452706/php-variable-not-accessible-defined-in-include-require-file-using-absolute-path Still, I strongly think it's because of this particular problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it to work by changing the url of the $.get to a function in my controller.
Then in that function i loaded the flips.php and send $data (an array with all variables from userInfo.php) with it.

Answer (score 1):

#### File system

```
<path-to-views-dir>/steamauth/userInfo.php
<path-to-views-dir>/gebruiker/home/flips.php
<path-to-views-dir>/gebruiker/home/home.php
```

#### userInfo.php

```
<?php

$variable = "Hello everyone, I am the coolest variable!";

echo 'Hello from userInfo.php!<br/>';
```

#### flips.php

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/../../steamauth/userInfo.php';

if (isset($variable)) {
    echo 'Helo from flips.php. The variable is set.<br/>';
} else {
    echo 'Helo from flips.php. The variable is NOT set.<br/>';
}
```

#### home.php

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/flips.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (isset($variable)) {
    echo 'Hello from home.php. The variable is set.<br/>';
} else {
    echo 'Hello from home.php. The variable is NOT set.<br/>';
}
```

#### ...or home.php (fetching flips.php content through ajax)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#testButton').click(function (event) {
                    alert('testButton clicked!');

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: 'flips.php',
                        data: {},
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $('#results').html(response);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            $('#results').html(textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
                        },
                        cmplete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            //...
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 30px;
            }

            button {
                padding: 5px 10px;
                background-color: #8daf15;
                color: #fff;
                border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button type="button" id="testButton" name="testButton">
            Fetch some data
        </button>

        <br/><br/>

        <div id="results">
            Here comes the response data from the ajax request...
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### To do

In browser, access the home.php page.

Comment: @Smokey Well, there is something which doesn't fit... It would be very helpful if you would give us the whole codes. Otherwise I don't think that someone of us could help you. I might be wrong though :-)

Comment: I just got it by changing the url from the $.get to a function in my controller, and then loading flips.php with $data (in which are all the variables from userInfo.php), thanks for all your help anyway!

Comment: @Smokey You are welcome. Good to know that it's working now.